# CSS Grid - Auto height rows, sizing to content

Tags: css, css-grid

I have two grids nested within a grid. Unfortunately the right nested grid `.grid-3` sets the height of the rows so that both the left and right grid are the same height, the extra space is shared among the divs with the class `.right`. How can I set the rows of the right nested grid to adjust to the size of the content, so they are the same height as the left nested rows?

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}
 
.right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-2">
      <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-3">
         <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-rows: max-content`

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-2">
  <div class="grid-2">
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
    <div class="left">L</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3">
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="right">R</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `grid-3` will take all parent height here. If you want `grid-3`'s height to fit content you can use [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49716873/1548895).

Answer (score 70):

By default grid items stretch to all grid cell area. So you have this options here if you want grid's height to fit content:

- Set alignment for all items using `align-items` for grid container (default value is `align-items: stretch`). So just set `align-items: start` for `grid-2`. Demo:

  ```css
  div {
    border: 1px dotted black;
  }

  .grid-2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: start;
  }

  .grid-3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }

  .left {
    background-color: red;
  }
   
  .right {
    background-color: green;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="grid-2">
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
       </div>
       <div class="grid-3">
           <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
       </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Set alignment for grid items individually using `align-self` (default value is `align-self: stretch`). So just set `align-self: start` for `grid-3`. Demo:

  ```css
  div {
    border: 1px dotted black;
  }

  .grid-2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .grid-3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-self: start;
  }

  .left {
    background-color: red;
  }
   
  .right {
    background-color: green;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="grid-2">
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
       </div>
       <div class="grid-3">
           <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
       </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Set alignment for grid items individually using `margin` property with `auto` values. Auto margins for grid cell take all available space in any direction. So just set `margin-bottom: auto` for `grid-3`. Demo:

  ```css
  div {
    border: 1px dotted black;
  }

  .grid-2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .grid-3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }

  .left {
    background-color: red;
  }
   
  .right {
    background-color: green;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="grid-2">
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
          <div class="left">L</div>
       </div>
       <div class="grid-3">
           <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
          <div class="right">R</div>
       </div>
  </div>
  ```

If you want right grid to take all parent vertical space but make its cells to fit content use `align-items: start` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78184865/1548895). Demo:

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: start;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}
 
.right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-2">
      <div class="grid-2">
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="left">L</div>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-3">
         <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solutions you proposed are good but then another problem arises: there is an extra space created by the margin which is not filled with content. How can I say to the grid system that I just need elements in columns? Maybe I should use flex here... Thanks

Comment: @LucioB Sorry, didn't understand your question. Maybe it's better to ask a separate question with all details and examples and post the link here to me in comments.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing, LucioB is saying that with `align-items: start`, the bottom of the grid content ends where the content ends not where the grid cell ends, so then the next row below it has an extra size gap.

Comment: Every comment/answer like this on Stackoverflow gives me a powerful knowledge about programming. Thank you.

Comment: Every comment/answer like this makes me wonder why nobody can be bothered to study documentation and learn the correct properties. All "solutions" here are workarounds. Learn about the difference of grid tracks and cells, then use align-content:start and be happy.

Comment: Hi @Rolf, I want to point out that your answer is not very polite and respectful. I do see that your answer is much better than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701488/1548895) which is accepted at the moment. My solution is for the case when you want nested grid's height to match its content. This might be not very useful for OP, but potentially helpful for other users. I shared the link to your answer for the case when nested grid's height matches its container.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try `grid-auto-rows: fit-content(1em);`.  Of course, use whatever sizing makes sense for you.  I also tried the approach described by 
Temani (`minmax(min-content, max-content)`) and the results were identical when rendering my HTML.

According to [Elad Schechter - Medium](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7gJuywsDoAhXaB80KHQeRAi4QFjABegQIFRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40elad%2Fbecoming-a-css-grid-ninja-f4c6db018cc1&usg=AOvVaw1SueCz9ewuvEEqeNbeiR9y),

> The fit-content function accepts one param, the maximum value. ... The fit-content() function is similar to using the minmax() function, with a minimum value of 0. One key difference: The minmax() is more likely to occupy the max space allowed, while the fit-content does not occupy any more space than necessary.

Your needs will determine whether `fit-content` is more appropriate than using `minmax` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `align-content:start`, not align-items.

With `align-content`, you control the placement of the grid **rows** (more general: the tracks in block axis direction). The default is `stretch`, which causes the track size to increase to fill remaining free space. Use `align-content:start`, then the free space stays where it is.

With `align-items`, you control the placement of the grid **cells** within the track. The default is also `stretch`, which causes the cells to fill their track in block direction. With `start`, the cell size is determined by its content, but the grid track stays stretched.