# problem with vertical spacing with css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, css-grid

**Note**  `div.text` first two div always will be top (also second div will be sticky div)  and other div will be add dynamically from the bottom by `js` `insertAdjacentHTML()`

I am getting an extra space between two `div.text` vertically

**is there is possible way to resolve with `css grid` ?**

**Final Result**

```css
  *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr)  ;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
   color:#000;
  height:300px;
  
}

.grid-container > div.item {
   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.grid-container > div.item div.text {
   align-self: end;
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content ;
}
.grid-container > div.item div.text:nth-child(2){
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:red;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>
     
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
    <div class="text">
        <span>Web App</span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
  <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**Initial problem with vertical space when two or three `div.text` added**

```css
  *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr)  ;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
   color:#000;
  height:300px;
  
}

.grid-container > div.item {
   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.grid-container > div.item div.text {
   align-self: end;
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content ;
}
.grid-container > div.item div.text:nth-child(2){
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:red;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>
     
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
    <div class="text">
        <span>Web App</span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
  <div class="text">
        <h6>Title One</h6>
        <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
   
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**What it looks like initially when two divs are added**

[image]

Comment: the question is not clear. what do you want achieve?

Comment: @Becky `<div class="text">` first and second div will be place vertically from the top.. others dive will be from the bottom

Comment: please.. if anyone not clear after reading the question what i try to achieve.. i put my answer..  please check the answer .. see two result ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;` and it will fix your issue.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-container>div.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.grid-container>div.item div.text {
  align-self: end;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

.grid-container>div.item div.text:nth-child(2) {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
      here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
      Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
      The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
      Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      <span>Web App</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>1</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>2</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>3</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>4</i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution. I found the same response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701408/css-grid-auto-height-rows-sizing-to-content but why don't you simply use `grid-auto-rows: max-content;`

Comment: @devdgehog I suppose you could use any of `minmax(min-content, max-content)` or `min-content` or `max-content`.

Comment: @Dipen Shah i put my answer please check ... i think you did not understand my question ...  first two div always will be top (also second div will be sticky div) and other div will be add dynamically from the bottom by js..

Comment: @noor I think I understand it now. Take a look at changes I made to my answer `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;` will give what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `align-content: end;` in your `.grid-container>div.item { ... }`. I have commented it in the code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-container>div.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  /*align-content: end;*/  /* removed this */
  align-items: end; /* added this */

  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container>div.item div.text:first-child {
  align-self: start;
}

.grid-container>div.item div.text:first-child h1 {
  /*align-self: start;*/   /* removed this */

  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.grid-container>div.item div.text:not(:first-child) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Web App</p>
      <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h6>Title One</h6>
      <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for removing  space ...   i add  `align-content: end;`..

Comment: replace that with `align-items: end;` to bottom align

Comment: also others div vertically not end of bottom

Comment: you have set `align-self: start;` for your first 2 `.item` div. I just edited my answer. try that

Comment: i upload expected  pic .. please review question ..

Comment: @noor a word of advise, you have to take your time before posting your question. Adding bits and pieces later on isn't going to help you.

Comment: think about chat app .. first two div will be top and other div or message  will be push from the bottom

Comment: when more div will be populate then scrollbar appear and when user scroll sticky div will work..

Comment: @Becky if you don't understand please leave a comment..

Comment: Is there any specific reason to have `<p>Web App</p>` and `<h1>Sticky Dive</h1>` inside two seperate parents? That can be inside the same parent. you can then easily specify the bottom alignment only to the bottom 2 divs with `:not(:first-child). `see my edit.

Comment: firstly thanks for your time ..what about sticky div ? there are also space between last two div ..

Comment: what's the reason for using two `text` parents there?

Comment: @Becky sorry for disturb you again .. i update my question .. if you have time ..please review...

Answer (score 0):

**Note: if anyone can give better solution. Answer will be acceptable**

**I resolve my problem by wrapping tag**

```
<div class="text">
    <span>Web App</span>
</div>
 <div class="text">
    <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
</div>
 <div class="text">
     <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
     </div>
      <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Initial Result**

```css
  *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    margin:0;
   padding:0;

}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr)  ;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
   color:#000;
  height:300px;
  
}

.grid-container div.item {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
   grid-template-rows: min-content ;

   align-items: start;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;

}


.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2)  div.text {

  margin-top: 2px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr  ;
 
}


.grid-container  > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(2){
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:red;
  align-self: start;
}

.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(3)  {
  align-self: end;
}

.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(3)  div.message{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
   grid-template-rows: min-content ;
   border: 1px dotted royalblue;
   margin-top: 2px;
   padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>
     
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text" >
        <span>Web App</span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Final Result**

```css
  *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr)  ;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #f7ca18;
  padding: 10px;
   color:#000;
  height:300px;
  
}

.grid-container div.item {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
   grid-template-rows: min-content ;

   align-items: start;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;

}


.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2)  div.text {
  margin-top: 2px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr  ;
}


.grid-container  > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(2){
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background:red;
  align-self: start;
}

.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(3)  {
  align-self: end;
}

.grid-container > div.item:nth-child(2) > div.text:nth-child(3)  div.message{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
   grid-template-rows: min-content ;
   border: 1px dotted royalblue;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>
     
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
    <div class="text" >
        <span>Web App</span>
    </div>
     <div class="text">
        <h1>Sticky Dive</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>

        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>

        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div><div class="message">
          <h6>Title One</h6>
          <span>Hello - <i>X</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
 
   
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe there is a simple way with `grid-auto-rows` take a look a my answer.

Comment: I think you are talking about reduce the horizontal space between 1st (title one) and 2nd (Hello-X) column. In that case adding, "padding-right:250px;padding-left:100px;"  in ".grid-container > div.item div.text {" will help you out.